# Using function from model in view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

In CakePHP I've a model Customer which looks like this:

```
<?php

class Customer extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'Invoice',
        )
    );

    public function getDisplayName($id){
        $customer = new Customer(); 
        $customer_array = $customer->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('Customer.id' => $id)
        ));

        if($customer_array['Customer']['company']){
            return $customer_array['Customer']['company'];
        } else {
            return $customer_array['Customer']['frontname'] . ' ' . $customer_array['Customer']['lastname'];
        }
    }

    public function getFullName($id){
        $customer = new Customer(); 
        $customer_array = $customer->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('Customer.id' => $id)
        ));

        return $customer_array['Customer']['frontname'] . ' ' . $customer_array['Customer']['lastname'];
    }

}
?>
```

In an other view (Project) I want to show a list of customers with there display name (because some of them have an company and others don't).

So in the ProjectController I added this:

```
$customers = $this->Project->Customer->find('list', array(
    'fields' =>array(
        'Customer.id', $this->Project->Customer->getDisplayName('Customer.id')
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Customer.cloud_id' => '1'
    )
));             
$this->set('customers', $customers);
```

But then I get an MySQL error because the second field isn't a databasecolumn.

Who can help me with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best best would be using virtual fields in your Customer model:
See the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

```
<?php
class Customer extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'Invoice',
        )
    );
    public $virtualFields = array(
        'display_name' => 'IF(Customer.company IS NOT NULL, Customer.company, CONCAT_WS(' ', Customer.frontname, Customer.lastname))'
    );
}
?>
```

Then in projects controller:

```
<?php
$customers = $this->Project->Customer->find('list', array(
    'fields' =>array(
        'Customer.id', 'Customer.display_name'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Customer.cloud_id' => '1'
    )
));             
$this->set('customers', $customers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question more generally (here the virtual fields solutions works fine), you could rewrite the getDisplayName function and put in in your Controller.

Then you could call it from the view using

```
$displayName= $this->requestAction(array(
  'controller'=>'CustomersController',
  'action'=>'getDisplayName ')
);

echo $displayName;
```